# How to Erlang binary combine?

Tags: erlang

Given

```
[<<"1 coin">>, <<"2 cash">>, <<"3 coin">>]
```

I want:

```
<<"1 coin, 2 cash, 3 coin">>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to concatenate 2 binaries is `<<B1/binary, B2/binary>>`. It is not often used since list of binaries are generally so called iolist, and are directly manipulated by most libraries in Erlang.

As you not only want to flatten your list but also add those `", "` between each terms, you can write your own recursive function or use the lists:foldl/3:

```
1> Concat = fun(L) -> [H|T] = lists:reverse(L), lists:foldl(fun(X,Acc) -> <<X/binary,", ",Acc/binary>> end, H, T) end.
#Fun<erl_eval.6.90072148>
2> Concat([<<"1 coin">>, <<"2 cash">>, <<"3 coin">>]).                                                                               
<<"1 coin, 2 cash, 3 coin">>
3>
```